# Is it wrong to pass undefined to React setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have the following state declared on my React component:

```
const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState<IUser['id'][]>();
```

Said state is used as the value for a third party HTML `<select />` ([Ant Design](https://ant.design/)).

After I'm done using the `<select />` I would like to clear it, which I easily can do by setting the value as `null` or `undefined`.

E.g.:

```
setSelectedUsers(null);
```

```
<select value={selectedUsers} /> // Is now null, no option is selected
```

However, I cannot pass `null` as the `<select />` value due to the expected TS props on the select component as it expects to receive `<IUser['id'][] | undefined>`.

I.e.:

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string[] | undefined'.
```

Given the context above, is there any problem with passing `undefined` to the React state?

I.e.:

```
setSelectedUsers(undefined);
```

This is a question about best practices as the code above works perfectly if I use `undefined` instead of `null`.

Comment: nothing wrong with that but in my opinion, if it's gonna be an array, why not just initialize it as an empty array, also setting as empty array after you are done with it?

Comment: @İlker Yep, that was the solution mikeb came up with in our chat discussion: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236326/discussion-between-gustavo-maximo-and-mikeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it `[] as string[]`

`setSelectedUsers([] as string[]);`

That should do it.

Edited to include the stuff in the comments:

The way the original question was worded you're type is a one-element array, this should be defined as:

```
const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState<string[]>();
```

Then, the solution above will work.

Comment: What do you mean `SetStateAction<string`... shouldn't it be `string[]`? Why don't you do `[] as string[]`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, ignore that error. The TS error I get if I do `setSelectedUsers([] as string[]);` is `Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<[string] | null | undefined>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[string]'.
    Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.`

Comment: So you can only select one user at a time? I don't get that, but ok...

Comment: That error occurs because I'm passing an empty array and it expects an array of users, for instance if I do: `setSelectedUsers(['']);` TS doesn't give a warning, but `setSelectedUsers([]);` does.

Comment: It actually expects a one-element array, if you wanted to pass it an array you'd do: `useState<string[]>();`

Comment: If you try to do `setSelectedUsers(['1', '2'])` typescript will complain b/c your type is not quite correct.

Comment: Yes sir that is true, I didn't realize that. Changing the state type declaration from `<[IUser['id']] | null>` to `<IUser['id'][] | null>` fixed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236326/discussion-between-gustavo-maximo-and-mikeb).

Answer (score 4):

Passing `undefined` as a value onto setState is perfectly fine. The value of the state, in your case `selectedUsers`, can be of any JavaScript type.

`undefined` is a "Primitive Value" in JavaScript and therefore a regular type. Find more about JavaScript types here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#javascript_types

Answer (score 0):

The type and constructor should be

```
const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState<[IUser['id']] | null>(null);
```

if you want `null` to be the null value. (`undefined` implicitly works since you don't pass in an initial state, since that's implicitly `undefined`.)

However, if you want to be able to select multiple values, you are probably looking for

```
const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState<Array<IUser['id']> | null>(null);
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but it won't work with Ant Design.

Comment: Then you'll probably want to pass `value={... ?? undefined}` to the AntD component to turn nulls into undefineds.

Comment: Yes sir! That worked perfectly. If you want to incorporate that into your answer I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: For clarification, I did pass `null` to the state instead of `undefined` to clear the select. Then on the `value={}` of the `<select />` I added the nullish coalescing operator.